# Regex result with no especial Character (exclude some chars)

Tags: regex

Imagine we want to extract all strings which starts with `1` and ends with `aa>>>` from a file .

So we will use this regex :

```
1(.*)+a{2}>>>$
```

This Regex will return all values witch contains `aa>>>`

For example with testing regex on `32 123.123.bmp aa>>>` it will return  `123.123.bmp aaa>>>`

Is There any way to exclude `aa>>>` from result ?

For above example I want  `123.123.bmp` as result .

Comment: Use a lookahead, `1(.*?)(?=\s*a{2}>>>$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks , can you explain what does ?=\s* mean ?

Comment: `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespaces, but the main point is the lookahead, `(?=....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
1.*?(?=\s*a{2}>>>$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AOYtvx/1)

**Details**

- `1` - `1` char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*a{2}>>>$)` - a positive lokahead (non-consuming pattern that does not add the matched text to the whole match (Group 0) value) that requires (immediately to the right of the current location):

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `a{2}` - two `a`s
  - `>>>$` - `>>>` at the end of the string.

To match only when `1` is not preceded with another digit use a `(?<!\d)` lookbehind:

```
(?<!\d)1.*?(?=\s*a{2}>>>$)
```

or a word boundary:

```
\b1.*?(?=\s*a{2}>>>$)
```